# Show that the points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which lie on a line through ${\bf p}+t {\bf v}$ and ${\bf q}$ (some $t\in\mathbb{R}$) make up a plane

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Show that the points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which lie on a line through ${\bf p}+t {\bf v}$ and ${\bf q}$ (some $t\in\mathbb{R}$) make up a plane.

That's kind of confusing, so hopefully this helps:
[image]

---

Equation of plane is $d=a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)$, where $[a,b,c]$ is the **normal vector**, and $[x_0,y_0,z_0]$ is a **point on the plane**.

Everyting in $\mathbb{R}^3$

---

A point **on the plane** is any point on the line $l$.

The line $l=[l_1,l_2,l_3]$ can be written as $[p_1+tv_1,p_2+tv_2,p_3+tv_3]$

That is a point on the line.

**A normal vector** to the plane is the vector from any point on $l$ to the point $q$.

Normal = $[q_1-(p_1+tv_1),q_2-(p_2+tv_2),q_3-(p_3+tv_3)]$

---

Then I can plug into the equation and solve. Is this correct? It's hard for me to visualize this but I think it is okay.

Comment: not the best grammar. I would say on the union of all the lines. Also, to get a plane, it is necessary that $q$ can not be expressed as $p+tv$ for any $t$

Comment: The vector that you say is normal to the plane is in fact parallel to it.

Comment: @amd it depends which way you look at the plane doesnt it. If you think of the plane as "sidways" it is normal

Comment: No, it really doesn’t. You’re not going to decrease your confusion by making up your own definitions for well-established terms (whatever Humpty-Dumpty might say). A “normal” vector to the plane is perpendicular to it. Moreover, you’re using the word to mean two very different things in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector to a plane is usually found using the cross product of two linearly independent vectors in the plane. Now we know that **v** is a vector in the plane and since both **p** and **q** are points in the plane, a normal vector is the cross product of **v** and **q-p**.

Comment: How do you know that $v$ is a vector on the plane? The line it made up of $p+tv$

Comment: Since all points **p+tv** are in the plane, the particular points **x1=p+1v** and **x0 = p+0v** are in the plane. Therefore the vector from **x0**  to **x1** is in the plane....

Comment: Ok, instead of **q-p**, could you have also done **v-p**, since that too is still on the plane?

Comment: Since $\vec{v}\times(\vec{v}-\vec{p})=(\vec{v}\times\vec{v})-(\vec{v}\times\vec{p})=(\vec{v}\times\vec{p})$, the answer is "maybe".